# something wrong with css Image gallery ..?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I am using the trying to use Jquery Image Gallery but somehow the navigation icons dont show up and even the 'Loading' icon show up on click...

the code used is :

```
  .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-prev .ad-prev-image, .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-next .ad-next-image {
    background: url(ad_prev.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 101;
  }
  .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-next .ad-next-image {
    background: url(ad_next.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
  .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-image .ad-image-description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(opa75.png) #ededed;
    color: #000;
  }
```

Here s the link to the page: http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/index.php

Answer (score 3):

The paths to the images are wrong. The browser is showing 404 messages for them. Check the path and make sure they exist. On an unrelated note, you may also want to consider upgrading the version of jQuery you're using.

```
GET http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/loader.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/ad_next.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/ad_prev.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/ad_scroll_back.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.thekashmirscenario.com/gallery/ad_scroll_forward.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: do u have a link to the upgraded jquery...? that wud be helpful :)

Comment: You can always grab the latest copy from http://jquery.com/ to host on your server, or link to a hosted version like on jquery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js or http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) or Google (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js  or https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js)